# Split overlapping intervals into smaller, touching ones in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a help with a query that should split some overlapping date intervals in the following way.

For example if we have a following table

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   column_name    |    value    |    start_date    |    end_date    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     column1      |    value1   |    03-09-2020    |   26-09-2020   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     column1      |    value2   |    07-09-2020    |   20-09-2020   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a problem coming up with a query to make the following output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   column_name    |    value    |    start_date    |    end_date    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     column1      |    value1   |    03-09-2020    |   07-09-2020   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     column1      |    value2   |    07-09-2020    |   20-09-2020   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     column1      |    value1   |    20-09-2020    |   26-09-2020   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How do you prioritize? Based on column_name, or value?

Comment: So when i get the results from the first table, that means that ,,column1,, had ,,value1,, from 03-09-2020 to 07-09-2020. Then the value switched to value2 from 07-09-2020 and it was there till 20-09-2020 when it switched back to the value1 to 26-09-2020. I realized i amde a mistake. Colum2 should be Column1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to get all the dates and use a lateral join to figure out the value on that date:

```
with dates as (
      select start_date as date
      from t
      union 
      select end_date
      from t
     )
select tt.value, d.date as start_date, lead(d.date) over (order by d.date) as end_date
from dates d left join lateral
     (select t.*
      from t
      where start_date <= d.date and
            end_date > d.date
      order by start_date desc  -- this gets the most recent overlapping value
      limit 1
     ) tt
     on true
order by d.date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=34b4c967394b5c1eae5c4a8018f8bfcd) is a db<>fiddle.

Note this adds an extra row with the final "no value" period.  You can easily filter that out if you don't want it.